# Can I run ffmpeg -f x11grab for a specified amount of time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to run `ffmpeg -x11grab` for a specified amount of time, sneding the output to a file. (This is on a Debian system, `ffmpeg` 7:4.0.2-1)

I have already tried the `-t` switch, as below:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab  -y -r 60  -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -t 10 -vf format=gray -pix_fmt yuv420p myfile
```

but it won't stop after 10 seconds. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: try `-t` before `-i`

Comment: Share te log of your command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest the `timeout` command. I use it with ffmpeg to record a live HTTP stream.

```bsh
$ timeout --help
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

DURATION is a floating point number with an optional suffix:
's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.
```

It should come pre-installed on most linux distributions. For 10 seconds, simply run:

```bsh
$ timeout 10s ffmpeg -f x11grab  -y -r 60  -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -vf format=gray -pix_fmt yuv420p myfile
```

Plesae note that there is also [another timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout), which adds the ability to limit by memory and CPU frequency too.

---

As for your problem with ffmpeg, this is from `man ffmpeg`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       ffmpeg [global_options] {[input_file_options] -i input_url} ... {[output_file_options] output_url} ...
```

You need to move `-t` argument before `-i`.

Comment: Moving the `-t` before `-i` solved it! Thank you!

Comment: If I answered your question it would be nice if you would mark it accepted.